# Notify child Component that Promise has ended so then children component can execute a method (react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know if the title is the best one but, the problem is that I have a parent Component in React Native.
Inside this parent component, I fetch some location data (countryName, countryCode, etc).
This data is required for the children to fetch more data on its own to get specific info based on countryName. I just simply do an HTTP GET fetch() in the child.

Now, happens that whenever children's `componentDidMount` method is ran, I still don't have `this.props.countryName` available, therefore, my fetch inside the children Component fails to retrieve data.

I would like to somehow, whenever ParentComponent finishes fetching Location data, to notify ChildrenComponent so he can `getAllReports()` by countryName.

Here's my current code:

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            countryName: '',
            regionName: '',
            countryCode: ''
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.getLocationData();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <ChildComponent countryName={ this.state.countryName }></ChildComponent>
        )
     },

     getLocationData() {
        fetch(Constants.GEO_URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                countryName: responseJson.country_name,
                regionName: responseJson.region_name,
                countryCode: responseJson.country_code
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Failed to get location data');
        });
    }
})
```

And this would be ChildComponent

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            reports: []
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.getAllReports().catch((error) => { console.log("ERROR on getAllReports() - ") });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollView refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={ this.state.refreshing }
                        onRefresh={ this._onRefresh }
                        title={ i18n.t('loading') }
                      />
                  }>
                { this.listReports() }
            </ScrollView>
        )
     },

    listReports: function() {
        if (this.state.reports.length > 0) {
            return this.state.reports.map(function(report, key) {
                return <ReportItem key={ key } item={ report } />
            });
        }else{
            return <Text style={ styles.statusMessage }>{ i18n.t('noMissingError') }</Text>
        }
    },

    getAllReports: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var url = Constants.API_LOCAL_URL + '/reports' + '?country=' + this.props.countryName;
            console.log('URL > ' + url);
            fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson)
                this.setState({
                    reports: responseJson
                });
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Error retrieving reports.');
                reject();
            })
        });
    }
})
```

As you may see, whenever ChildComponent is rendered, it doesn't have any countryCode, so it fails to retrieve. Also, i added the RefreshControl, so it actually retrieves data when i pull up on ScrollView, reloads all and get all the data... but just because I get the countryName afterwards.

I was looking for some way to do like trigger events from components and have a listener in others. Seems like there's no way to do that.

Any suggestion on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution maybe to fetch all of the data you need and then pass it down to the child component. That way the fetch is isolated to the parent, and you can guarantee its there before.

The beauty of the Promise is you can just keep going:

```
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error("Bad response from server");
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // fetch here again if needed can also set state here or in next .then
    that.setState({ person: data.person });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, i tried doing that, passing reports to child, but child doesn't update its view because i have to trigger a "listReports()" back again in order to display them.

Comment: Also, how come would the fetch data be isolated from parent if i'm calling to get all the data from the parent itself? i didn't understand that :(

Comment: Okay, so i ended up solving it differently. I had the app component with some calls where i just modulated the functionalities and passed it to the child component directly so there i do the getLocation and getReports directly from the same component... it was easier that way and it even has more sense to have it there because my header is part of the view too... when i change the tab it will also change the header... that's why it made sense. Thanks.